# Updating state makes array render bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have 4 buttons, which updates the state "mode":

```
<tr><button value = {0} name="mode" onClick={this.handleChange}>Montrer toutes les chambres</button></tr>
<tr><button value = {1} name="mode" onClick={this.handleChange}>Montrer les chambres vides</button></tr>
<tr><button value = {2} name="mode" onClick={this.handleChange}>Montrer les chambres avec de la place</button></tr>
<tr><button value = {3} name="mode" onClick={this.handleChange}>Montrer les chambres pleines</button></tr>

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name] : event.target.value});
}
```

this state change the render based on an array

```
let txt = myarray.map((item) => {
        console.log(this.state.mode);
        console.log(item);
        if(item===null)
            return(<div>Problème</div>);
        if(this.state.mode===0)
            return(<div>{item.info}</div>);
        else if ((this.state.mode===1)&& (b1))
            return(<div>{item.info}</div>);
        else if((this.state.mode===2) && (b2))
            return (<div>{item.info}</div>);
        else if((this.state.mode===3) && (b3))
            return (<div>{item.info}</div>);
        else return(<div>Invalid item</div>);
    });
return txt;
```

`mode` is set to `0` when I launch the program, and everything works. However, when I change the `mode`, every item returns Invalid item (even for `mode=0`). I tried to set b1,b2, and b3 to `true` for testing but it doesn't work, so that's not the problem. The 2 `console.log` works fine and shows the right values.

Could someone help me? Is the value of the problem?

Comment: Did you bind `this.handleChange` to the react this on the constructor? And is there an error or just the value you want is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Parse value to integer

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name] : parseInt(event.target.value)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just send it as a Number arg (which you are trying to check later with if statements) arg in the function as such:

```
<tr>
  <button name="mode" onClick={e => this.handleChange(e,3)}>
    Montrer les chambres pleines
  </button>
</tr>

handleChange(event, value) {
  this.setState({[event.target.name] : value});
}
```